# Eclipse Java EE: Difference between R and M1 packages

Tags: eclipse

I want to install Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and stumbled upon

[*eclipse-jee-mars-**R**-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz*](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/marsr)

and

[*eclipse-jee-mars-**M1**-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz*](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/marsm1).

Both for Linux 64bit. What is the difference between those packages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'M1' release is an old Milestone 1 release of Eclipse Mars, this is completely obsolete and should not be used.

The 'R' release is the actual release of Mars.

Stick to the downloads shown on https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/